# SEEK frame in id3v2 tag of MP3 audio file

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, id3

How do I add a `SEEK` frame while adding the id3v2 tag of a .mp3 file using ffmpeg?

Which id3 tags can be added using FFmpeg? What are the commands to do so?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I add a SEEK frame while adding the id3v2 tag of a .mp3 file using ffmpeg?

As far as I know, this is not possible with ffmpeg. It seems that manually setting this frame is not useful anyway, since the ID3v2 writing library should take care of properly specifying it.

> Which id3 tags can be added using FFmpeg?

There is [an extensive overview](http://jonhall.info/create_id3_tags_using_ffmpeg/) of which ID3(v2) tags can be written with ffmpeg and what the respective `<key>` is, since ffmpeg's keys and ID3(v2) keys are not equivalent. You can also have a look at the [`id3v2.c` source file](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/id3v2.c) to check the available tags and their metadata key.

> What are the commands to do so?

Generally, you specify metadata values by using the `-metadata <key>=<value>` option, e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -metadata title="Foo" -metadata artist="Bar" <output>
```

Note that ffmpeg doesn't throw an error if you use a tag that does not exist in the ID3v2 specification.